# Android put images from server into listview

Tags: php, android, image, listview, server

I want to take pictures from my PHP server and put it into my android ListView

I am using the code example in https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-programming-tutorial-to-get-all-images-from-server but this only gets all of the images and shows them one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really try to be using Android Volley for data transfers. It is developed by the Android team and is the recommended convention.

http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

And as far as your list view goes, unless you have some specific reason to use it, you may want to look into Recyclerview. It handles most of the loading and view holding issues. http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html#RecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

Use android picasso library to get images to your app via url, its very easy to use. 
checkout this tutorial on the use of picasso

http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-use-picasso-library-in-android
hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is universal image loader. https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader